# How to use isdisit() for a character array(string)?

Tags: c

I am using C to develop my mini project. So here isdigit() works perfectly when I use it for a char(say char a) and get the input with a `scanf("%c",&a);`.But it fails when I use it for a string 
(say char a[5]) and get it with a `scanf("%s",a);`.
I expect that ,say if I give the input as 55 isdigit() it should evaluate to true and not when I give the input as say "Wd".

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()` is able to receive only one character as a argument.
It cannot understand character array.

If the `char a[5]` located in 0x38383838 on memory, `isdigit(a);` virtualy is `isdigit(0x38383838);`.
So it'll return 0 (or false).

If you want to test whether a character array is digit or not, then you should

```
int isdigit_array(char *a){
  int num = strlen(a);
  if(num == 0) return 0;

  int flag_isdigit = 1;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<num; i++){
    flag_isdigit = flag_isdigit && isdigit(a[i]);
  }
  return flag_isdigit;
}
```